# Catching stdout from bash.exe subprocess on Windows10 / WSL

Tags: c++, windows-10, stdout, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to spawn Bash.exe on Windows 10 as a child process in a c++ script. I want to leave the connection to bash open and pipe data back and forth between the parent process and bash.

There are a number of questions (such as [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/2)) related to this online, however, everything I can find predates the Windows 10 "Creators" update which supposedly includes windows/linux interoperability.

The code below works as intended if I spawn a native windows process such as netstat.exe. If I spawn bash.exe and try to read from the pipe, the read hangs indefinitely. That makes me think the data isn't being sent to STDOUT for the process, even post-creators update. Where does the output get sent - and is there any way to access it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <iostream>

HANDLE childStdInRead = NULL;
HANDLE childStdInWrite = NULL;
HANDLE childStdOutRead = NULL;
HANDLE childStdOutWrite = NULL;
HANDLE activeConsoleScreenBuffer = NULL;
CHAR returnedFromChild[4096] = {0};
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO currentConsoleScreenBuffer;

void CreateChildProcess();
void WriteToPipe(HANDLE writeTo, char passedChar);
void ReadFromPipe(HANDLE readFrom, CHAR* readto);
void ErrorExit(PTSTR);

int main()
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saAttr;

    // Set the bInheritHandle flag so pipe handles are inherited. 
    saAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    saAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;
    saAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDOUT. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&childStdOutRead, &childStdOutWrite, &saAttr, 0))
        printf("Error: StdOutRead CreatePipe! \n");

    // Ensure the read handle to the pipe for STDOUT is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(childStdOutRead, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        printf("Error: StdOut SetHandleInformation \n");

    // Create a pipe for the child process's STDIN. 
    if (!CreatePipe(&childStdInRead, &childStdInWrite, &saAttr, 0))
        printf("Error: StdInRead CreatePipe! \n");

    // Ensure the write handle to the pipe for STDIN is not inherited.
    if (!SetHandleInformation(childStdInWrite, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, 0))
        printf("Error: StdIn SetHandleInformation \n");

    //HANDLE activeConsoleScreenBuffer = GetStdHandle(11);

    printf("creating child process\n");
    CreateChildProcess();

    printf("waiting 3 seconds\n");
    Sleep(3000);

    printf("writing to pipe\n");

    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 't');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'o');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'u');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'c');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'h');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, ' ');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, '/');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 't');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'm');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'p');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, '/');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'a');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, '\n');

    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'e');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'x');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 'i');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, 't');
    WriteToPipe(childStdInWrite, '\n');

    printf("waiting 3 seconds\n");
    Sleep(3000);

    //CloseHandle(childStdOutWrite);
    //printf("activeConsoleScreenBuffer = ")
    printf("reading from pipe\n");
    ReadFromPipe(childStdOutRead, returnedFromChild);
    printf("%s\n", returnedFromChild);

    printf("waiting 5 seconds\n");
    Sleep(5000);
}

void CreateChildProcess(){
    // In order to launch bash in System32, program must be built as x64
    LPCTSTR applicationAddress = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe";
    //LPCTSTR applicationAddress = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\NETSTAT.EXE";
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcInfo;
    STARTUPINFO siStartInfo;

    // Set up members of the PROCESS_INFORMATION structure. 
    ZeroMemory(&piProcInfo, sizeof(PROCESS_INFORMATION));

    // Set up members of the STARTUPINFO structure. 
    // This structure specifies the STDIN and STDOUT handles for redirection.
    ZeroMemory(&siStartInfo, sizeof(STARTUPINFO));
    siStartInfo.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFO);
    siStartInfo.hStdError = childStdOutWrite;
    siStartInfo.hStdOutput = childStdOutWrite;
    siStartInfo.hStdInput = childStdInRead;
    siStartInfo.dwFlags |= STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;

    // Create the child process. 
    BOOL success = CreateProcess(
        applicationAddress, // absolute path to the application
        NULL,       // command line 
        NULL,               // process security attributes 
        NULL,               // primary thread security attributes 
        TRUE,               // handles are inherited 
        CREATE_NO_WINDOW,                  // creation flags 
        NULL,               // use parent's environment 
        NULL,               // use parent's current directory 
        &siStartInfo,       // STARTUPINFO pointer 
        &piProcInfo);       // receives PROCESS_INFORMATION 

    if (!success)
        printf("CreateProcess failed (%d).\n", GetLastError());
}

void WriteToPipe(HANDLE writeTo, char passedChar)
{
    DWORD read;
    BOOL success = FALSE;

    // writes passedChar to childStdinWrite pipe
    success = WriteFile(childStdInWrite, &passedChar, 1, &read, NULL);

    if (success) {
        printf("Successful write to pipe \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Write to pipe failed");
    }
}

void ReadFromPipe(HANDLE readFrom, CHAR* readTo)
{
    DWORD read;
    BOOL success = FALSE;
    success = ReadFile(readFrom, readTo, 1024, &read, NULL);

    if (success) {
        printf("Successful read from pipe \n");
    }
    else {
        printf("failed");
        ErrorExit(TEXT("ReadFromPipe failed"));
    }
}

void ErrorExit(PTSTR lpszFunction)

// Format a readable error message, display a message box,
// and exit from the application.
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0, NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
        (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
        lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
    MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    ExitProcess(1);
}
```

Comment: bash doesn't write a prompt to a pipe, so `touch /tmp/a` has no output text. The stdout pipe is thus empty and reading from it blocks. The reason it blocks is that there's another potential writer that you've left open. In `CreateChildProcess`, you're not closing your `childStdOutWrite` and `childStdInRead` handles. If you close that handle, expect to get `ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE` when trying to read from an empty pipe that's closed on the other end.

Comment: Thanks, I was expecting the prompt to be written to a pipe! 

Replacing the 'touch' command with an 'ls' does in fact allow reading from the pipe. So uh... where DOES the prompt get sent? Just drawn to the console screen buffer? Is there any other data that bash does not send to stdout - and where can I read up on this?

Regarding closing the handles, I need these pipes to remain open indefinitely. Does that mean I need to use an asynchronous/non-blocking setup with named pipes?

Comment: bash sees that stdin isn't a tty, so it disables interactive mode, which includes disabling the prompt. It's not written anywhere.

Comment: You'll be keeping the handles open for your end of the pipes, i.e. `childStdOutRead` and `childStdInWrite`. You're just closing the handles for the child's end. The pipes will remain open so long as the child process exists.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been really informative. If you'd like to post any of this as an answer, I'll accept it - my questions about this issue are covered in these comments.